# AsyncTaskLoader for loader and background thread getting ClassCastException when converting to androidx

Tags: java, android

My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            
    ArrayList<BookData> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,arrayList);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                   recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
            
    android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    Log.i(TAG, "Now calling initLoader");
    loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
            
            
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new 
    DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerview.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<List<BookData>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Problem with onCreateloader");
    return new BookLoader(MainActivity.this,GOOGLEBOOKURL);
}
            
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<List<BookData>> loader, List<BookData> data) {
    recyclerAdapter.clear();
    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        recyclerAdapter.addAll(data);
    }
}
            
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<List<BookData>> loader) {
    recyclerAdapter.clear();
    Log.i(TAG, "Now loader is resetting");
}
```

[Screenshot showing the class definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbHS8.png)

Errors:

```
Process: com.example.booklistapp, PID: 8575
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.booklistapp/com.example.booklistapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.booklistapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

I'm trying to solve this errors that I'm getting and in androidx, but there is no `initloader()` and `getManager()` to invoke the loader. How do I invoke the loader via initloader?

```
 android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            Log.i(TAG, "Now calling initLoader");
            loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

I used android app loader in androidx loader because there is no `initLoader()` and `getManager()` in androidx.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Madhan. There is a little info missing. I cannot see the imports for the cursor loaders or what "implements" the "LoaderCallback", but I've added a template below that should hopefully help.

Comment: see that in below comment I passed arraylist with custom class in callbacks, now where i need to pass cursor ? Thank you replying

Comment: Check out the screenshot bro Here both getSupportManager and getManager both are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I have loaders working in androidx:

My imports look like:

```
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment;
```

Fragments are like:

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<BookData>> {
```

Activities are like:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<BookData>>  {
```

You will need `AppCompatActivity`:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

And need to call `getSupportLoaderManager()` not `getLoaderManager()`:

```
LoaderManager lm = getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager();
```

But ideally you want to get rid of Loaders while they were a cornerstone of development, they are now deprecated.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<BookData>> {
    private static final String GOOGLEBOOKURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=search+terms";
    private static final String TAG = "Mainactivity";
  private   RecyclerView recyclerview;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private static final int BOOK_LOADER_ID = 1;

Comment: in callbacks i passed Arraylist which holds customclass ,here how i need to pass cursor

Comment: Sorry it was late when I wrote this...I should not have used Cursors in my example. But the principle is the same. The code needs to use the same androidx includes and access the loader manager via "getSupportLoaderManager" from AppCompatActivity. I've updated the loader to use your data now.

Comment: Did you check my screenshot? both getsupportmanager and getmanager deprecated in androidx

Comment: The entire concept of loaders is deprecated in Android, there is no replacement method as such. If you want to avoid the deprecation warnings, you will have to completely rewrite the code using ViewModels and LiveData if you want to be up to date with the latest trend. I was just trying to help get your existing code running again in androidx...

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that ASyncTaskLoader and ASyncTask are deprecated as well...

Comment: Np. Did you get your existing solution to run again?

Comment: Bro for getSupportManager() it is showing deprecated now i've used it for now afterwards I'll change ,Thank you bro

Comment: Great. Like I said using LiveData/ViewModel is more or less a complete rewrite. Can you please accept this answer as a solution for getting loaders working on androidx, by ticking the grey checkbox next to the answer. Cheers.